# Iterate through Incremental Raster Values in R to Create New Raster Datasets

Tags: r, loops, sequence, increment, raster

apologies if this has been asked before but I could not find a solution to my problem, which I believe is a rather simple problem. I have a single source raster dataset containing continuous floating values ranging between 100 and 500. What I would like to do is loop through this source raster in increments of 50 to export/create new raster datasets of all values that are lower than the increment. For example, I have the following R code (using the raster library) to specify the raster and identify the increments. I would to develop a way to automatically create 9 output raster datasets that are less than or equal to the values of each increment. I can't seem to get there.  Can anyone help?  TIA!

```
#Trying to iteratively create new raster datasets 
#Based on increments of Source Raster

library(raster)

setwd("C:/Path/To/Folder")

r=raster("Source_Raster.tif") #Raster is floating between 100 and 500

#Create a list of increments I would like to use
list <-seq(100, 500, 50)
#The list creates the following sequence:
# 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500

###THIS IS WHERE I STRUGGLE####
# I would like to use the sequence to create
# new raster datasets that only include values
# from the source raster that are less than or equal to each increment

# for example, the first output raster will contain values less than 
# or equal to the first increment (100)

r100 <- calc(r, fun=function(x){ x[x > 100] <- NA; return(x)} )
```

Answer (score 1):

After you determined the break points, we can use the `lapply` function to create each raster layer. In this example, `r_list` is the final output with 9 raster layers.

```
library(raster)

set.seed(145)

# Create example raster
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100, min = 100, max = 500), ncol = 10))

# Create break points
brk <-seq(100, 500, 50)

# Conduct the operation, create nine raster than smaller than each break points
r_list <- lapply(brk, function(x){ 
  temp <- r
  temp[temp > x] <- NA 
  return(temp)
  })
```

Comment: @LeeWalston Glad to help. Please consider to accept it as the answer if this solves your question.